# Discord.py client.get_guild(ID) returns NoneType even though it is a member of a guild

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
#Command works in DMs only
@commands.dm_only()
async def new_thread(ctx,channel_name: str, Id)
        guild = client.get_guild(Id)
        await ctx.send(guild.id)
        await guild.create_text_channel(channel_name)
```

Variable `guild` should return object class Guild but returns NoneType. As far as it goes, my bot is indeed a member of a guild and the Id I am using is also correct. What might be wrong?

Comment: Try to write `async def new_thread(ctx,channel_name: str, Id: int):` to convert `Id` to integer.

Comment: ^ didn't really work. Even when I copy-paste Id directly into the code, it still returns None

Comment: Then try to use `guild = await client.fetch_guild(Id)` instead of `guild = client.get_guild(Id)` and make sure that you provided existing ID.

Answer (score -1):

I made a bit of a mistake. A correct way to get a guild by its ID supposed to be `bot.get_guild(Id)` not `client.get_guild(Id)`

Comment: What's the difference? Aren't both discord.bot objects?